# System theme switch causes Android widget's click events become unresponsive

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget

I've implemented Android widget, and I've noticed that when users switch between the system's light or dark theme, the widget's click events become unresponsive.

When the theme is switched for the second time, the widget's click events start working again. The data from before the first switch is also retained after the second switch.
If my widget's functionality is to toggle between "a," "b," and "c" based on the number of clicks, then following the sequence of placing -> clicking -> (switching) -> clicking -> (switching) -> clicking, you will see "a," "b," "b," "c".

Furthermore, I noticed through breakpoints in Android Studio that after changing the system theme, neither onUpdate, onReceive, nor onAppWidgetOptionsChanged were triggered.

I suspect that the views private variable is being replaced with a new RemoteViews during the transition, but it's not triggering onUpdate, which is quite strange for me.

I googled some information but did not find a viable solution. I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide one solution.

WidgetProvider.kt

```
class WidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {
    private lateinit var views: RemoteViews

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)

            setupUpdateClickEvent(context, appWidgetId)

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }

    private fun setupUpdateClickEvent(context: Context, appWidgetId: Int) {
    val intent = Intent(context, WidgetProvider::class.java)
    intent.action = "UPDATE_CLICK"
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, appWidgetId, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.currentUpdateTextView, pendingIntent)
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.updateTextView, pendingIntent)
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)

        context?.let { RetrofitClient.checkApiKey(it) }
        context?.let { AppConfig.initialize(context) }

        when (intent?.action) {
            "UPDATE_CLICK" -> {
                val appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID
                )

                views = RemoteViews(context?.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)

                update(views, context, appWidgetId)
                // A function is used to modify the widget's display content with RemoteViews.
            }
        }
    }
    private fun update(..){
        // A function is used to modify the widget's display content with RemoteViews.
        // appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
    }
}
```

widget_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="110dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout">
</appwidget-provider>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.TornDashboard" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.TornDashboard" parent="Base.Theme.TornDashboard" />
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TornDashboard"
        android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
        tools:targetApi="tiramisu">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".widget.WidgetProvider"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: @TheLibrarian the widget's click events become unresponsive

Answer (score 0):

On click listeners seem to reset after system theme switch if a full update with `AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()` has been done without explicitly setting them with `RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent()`.

If all you do is modify display of some views in your `update(..)` function, you should use `AppWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget()` instead.

I had the same issue and this is the conclusion testing brought me to, as I too couldn't find anything in the documentation or the internet.